# Refactor to provide for multiple instances on a single page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a script that separates the date from a datepicker into day, month, and year. It works fine when there is one form on the page but not when there is a second one (presumably due to the id being the same). How can I add a value to my id and name so that they are unique values if the script runs twice on the same page?

```
var now = new Date();
var date = jQuery('.form-date');
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

date.val(today);

jQuery('form').on('submit', function() {

    var newVal = date.val().split('-'), 
        dateParts = {
            year: parseInt(newVal[0], 10),
            month: parseInt(newVal[1], 10),
            day: parseInt(newVal[2], 10)
        };

    jQuery('.anchor').append(jQuery.map(dateParts, function (index, key) {
        var name = 'date_' + key;

        return jQuery('<input>', {
            type: 'hidden',
            name: name,
            id: name,
            value: dateParts[key]
        });
    }));

});
```

Here is the form that isn't posting the correct date:

```
<form id="modal_res" action="http://www.site.com/search.php" method="get" name="disponibilita" target="_blank" class="custom">

            <ul>    
                <li>
                <label for="modal_date" class="anchor1"><?php _e('Date:', 'hostel_mama' )?></label><input type="date" name="date" id="modal_date" class="form-date datepicker">
                </li>

                <li>
                <label for="modal_nights"><?php _e('Nights:', 'hostel_mama' )?></label><input type="number" name="nights" id="modal_nights" value="2">
                </li> 

                <li>
<label for="modal_people"><?php _e('Guests:', 'hostel_mama' )?></label><input type="number" name="people" id="modal_people" value="1"> 
                </li>                                       

                <input name="ref" type="hidden" id="modal_ref" value="558" /> 
                <input name="langClient" type="hidden" id="modal_langClient" value="eng" />
                <li class="select-container">
                <label for="modal_expr"><?php _e('Currency:', 'hostel_mama' )?></label> 
                    <select name="expr" id="modal_expr">
        <option value="EUR" selected="selected"><?php _e('EURO', 'hostel_mama' )?></option>
        <option value="USD"><?php _e('US Dollar', 'hostel_mama' )?></option>
        <option value="GBP"><?php _e('British Pound', 'hostel_mama' )?></option>
        </select>
                </li>
                </ul>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button radius text-center" value="Click to Book">                    

            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure, so everything will be only inside it's scope. Additionally you can use $ now!

```
(function ($) {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = $('.form-date');
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);

    date.val(today);

    var form = $('form');

    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        var currentForm = $(this);
        var newVal = currentForm.find('.form-date').val().split('-'),

            dateParts = {
                year: parseInt(newVal[0], 10),
                month: parseInt(newVal[1], 10),
                day: parseInt(newVal[2], 10)
            };

        currentForm.find('.anchor').append($.map(dateParts, function (index, key) {
            console.log(['date', form.index(currentForm), key].join('_'));
            return $('<input>', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: ['date', key].join('_'),
                id: ['date', form.index(currentForm), key].join('_'),
                value: dateParts[key]
            });
        }));

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Also change class="anchor1" to class="anchor"

Edit: Whoops, looks like I'm wrong. You have to scope your selectors as $('.anchor').append will work on all .anchor elements. I'm assuming that it's the child of form now.

Comment: No still doesn't work. I think the problem is the id because it works when there is only one on a page. I think I need a unique value for `name`.

Comment: You are completely right - I've added form index as part of id/name.

Comment: I kept the name the same because thats what the form accepts and added another value for id. But apparently that's not the problem. It keeps posting `date_year=2013&date_month=11&date_day=8`which is what the form is initialised to. I think it is finding `.form_date` on the second form so I need a unique class for the second form. I'm going to test my theory now.

Comment: Aha, it works if I change the class in the second form to `form-date1`. Now can I do something like .find('.form-date', 'form-date1')?

Comment: Nope, change it back. You have to change all form.find to currentform.find, also change class in your html from anchor1 to anchor. http://jsfiddle.net/nmjP3/